# Laravel 5.2 WHERE LIKE has either a question mark or string without quotes

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

I'm trying to complete a search form in Laravel 5.2.  I've run into a problem where the $search will be a question mark in my sql query.  I've used ->toSql() to get the result of the query. I'm using DB::table() with a WHERE like this:

```
->where('clientname', 'LIKE', $search)
->orWhere('ClientFirstName', 'LIKE', [$search])
->orWhere('ClientLastName', 'LIKE', DB::raw($search))
```

Each of these create in different results in the query:

"where `clientname` LIKE ? or `ClientFirstName` LIKE ? or `ClientLastName` LIKE test "

Using the DB::raw() I get the search parameter from the form, but I can't make it a wildcard search with %, and I can't put single or double quotes around it to have the proper syntax to complete the search query.

Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code

```
->where('clientname', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')
->orWhere('ClientFirstName', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')
->orWhere('ClientLastName', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
->where(function ($q) use ($searchValues) {
            foreach ($searchValues as $value) {
                $q->orWhere('ClientFirstName', 'LIKE', "%{$value}%");
            }
        })
        ->orWhere(function ($q) use ($searchValues) {
            foreach ($searchValues as $value) {
                $q->orWhere('ClientLastName', 'LIKE', "%{$value}%");
            }
        })
```

I ended up going with this as my final working solution.